# Fresh installation of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bits

Tags: 12.04, installation, wireless

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bits on my Dell Inspiron 1501 computer and I want to reinstall (not upgrade) the 64 bits version. I don't know how to do that. Wifi doesn't work with my current version of Ubuntu and I have heard that it could work with the 64 bits version.

Answer (score 0):

Just FYI, you cannot upgrade from a 32bit to a 64bit, the only way is to do a complete reinstall. (I know that's what you wanted anyway, but I just wanted to clarify for any other potential readers).

You install the 64bit just like you installed the 32bit.

**Be warned, all your files will be overwritten so make sure you back up anything you want to keep** (unless you set up `/home` on a separate partition during the install of 12.04 32bit, in that case `/home` will not be touched during the install(you would have had to set this up manually it is not the default) Any programs that you installed will need to be reinstalled but see the lower part of my answer to see how to preserve any saved data(game saves and config customizations, etc)  As well as an easy way to save your documents(but save any important files in a regular backup just in case)

To install simply;

1. Boot from the LiveDvd/USB containing the *64bit* version of 12.04(download it from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) if you haven't already(note the 64bit is selected by default))
2. Select "Install Ubuntu"
3. Select "Replace Ubuntu 12.04 with 12.04)
4. Allow the installer to run and then reboot.

Your new install of 12.04 64bit will be completed but if you have any proprietary video drivers you will have to reinstall then via the "Additional Drivers" program again.

You will also need to install `ia32-libs` and `ia32-libs-multiarch:i386` so that you can run 32bit programs on the 64bot system.

---

**The following step is not necessary of you have your /home on a separate partition** and is optional in any case. For this to work, you **MUST** use the same profile(account) name in the new install that you used in the old or it will cause permission problems that may prevent you form accessing any of the files in your `/home` folder

Since you are "upgrading" from 32bit to 64bit and not to a newer version, you should be able to just save you home folder to another drive and then move it back over without worrying about any conflicts with your program configs(as sometimes happens with regular upgrade). When pasting back to the new home just let the old files overwrite the new ones(a window will pop up asking you if you want to do that, just select the box to apply to all files and then click yes)  This will save all your saved programs states from you old system so that when you reinstall all the programs, the settings and any game saved will be restored. As well as any other files you have saved in you profile.

Answer (score 0):

For one, DO NOT install the restricted driver.  It crashed my Dell 1501.

You will have to install the driver that is provided by Ubuntu.  The following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BroadcomSTA%28Wireless%29
will provide the instructions to install the right drivers.

WIFI will work in either 32 or 64 bit.  I have WIFI working in 64 bit.